# Sphinx string replacement in rst file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm new to sphinx and I need  to pass a value from `conf.py` to my rst files. Is this possible from within sphinx?

My use case is the following: I want to include code snippets that are generated along with the documentation. The problem is that the files reside in a build directory, and I have no way of knowing the relative path between the source and build directory.

index.rst:

```
.. literalinclude:: |BUILD_DIR|/generated.txt
```

The `conf.py` is generated at compile time and contains the path to the build directory.

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/45095529/407651

Comment: That’s true, but the answer with soft links doesn’t work for me since I have only read access to the source directory.

Comment: You can use substitutions to pass values from conf.py to .rst files. But you cannot use a substitution reference in the argument to the `literalinclude` directive. It would be nice if that worked, but it doesn't. Perhaps the program that generates conf.py can be augmented to also do a search-and-replace operation in the .rst files?

Comment: That’s what I’ll have to do if there is no possibility to it with Sphinx, but it would have been convenient with some kind of macro expansion in the rst files.